# Does .NET 4.5.1 works on core2duo processor?

Tags: c#, .net, intel

Some guys have developed a windows forms application using .NET 4.5.1 and they want to market it.

They want to buy a laptop to install that application on it in order to show the application to the customers.

They ask me about the mimimum requirements.

I plan to said this:

```
Name    Minimum Value
RAM 2 GB
Hard Disk Space Free Space 1 GB 
Monitor Driver Resolution   1366 x 768
Brand   Any Brand
Operating System    Windows 7
Processor   Intel Core 2 Duo
System Type Recommended 64 bit
```

my question is:

Does .NET 4.5.1 works on Core 2 Duo processor? and does Core 2 Duo Intel processor comes with 64bit?

Hope you help me though I know that this quetion maybe wrong.

Thanks

Comment: [.NET requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx). `.NET framework` has nothing to do with the CPU, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: @Loetn excellent and what is about the 64 bit please?

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_core_2 it is. I think next time you might google it yourself

Comment: IF you compile with "Any CPU" then it doesn't matter whether it is 32 or 64 bit. The JIT compiler will compile according to the CPU on the client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the questions:

> Does .NET 4.5.1 works on Core 2 Duo processor? and does Core 2 Duo Intel processor comes with 64bit?

Yes and Yes.

The actual hardware requirements will depend on the anticipated workload of the application much more than what framework or what framework version is used.

Comment: so you are saying that even if they develop the application using 64 bit, it doesn't matter if the customer has a 32 bit?

Comment: anyway my question is about having a core2duo and 64 and that is possible (as you said)

Comment: please are you sure? I could be fired from the company if that is not correct

Comment: Comment repeated from above: If you compile with "Any CPU" then it doesn't matter whether the CPU is 32 or 64 bit. The JIT compiler will compile according to the CPU on the client machine.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent I'm sure and, I'm sure I'm sure.

Comment: @Jodrell many thanks. However, you will be responsible to find me a new job if that wasn't  correct :) :)

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent If you target AnyCPU, you should at least test the 32 bit version. With pure managed code it's rare to have 32 vs 64 bit issues, but if you link with unmanaged code, you'll need extra work. And of course the address space is far smaller with 32 bit apps.

Comment: @CodesInChaos the applicaction is 2 windows forms. the first one has an image and a button, the second one has 3 labels and image and one input text box and a save button. does that really a `pure managed code` ? Anyway, I sent the mail already and lets wait for the response

Answer (score 1):

[The .NET Framework Requirements page,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx) as was linked in the comments, specifies minimum supported OS versions, RAM, disk-space and CPU speed (1GHZ), but says nothing of specific CPU models, so the Core 2 Duo shouldn't be a problem.

Regarding 64bit support, Intel's Core 2 Duo [specifications](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/core2duo/specifications.htm) page answers that question:

> All Intel® Core™2 Duo processors feature:
>
> - Intel® dual-core technology
> - Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® technology
> - Execute Disable Bit◊
> - **Intel® 64 architecture◊**

So yes, 64bit execution is supported.

Comment: are you sure that core 2 dou can be 64 bit please? I could be fired from the company if i gave a wrong information